# Plotting an Indicator with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I rewrote a indicator from another language into Python but my plot doesn't look like right. This is a Picture how the Plot should look like
[image]

But my plot look like this

[image]

Something it's wrong on the bottom part of my indicator but I don't how to fix it. My full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/G2uxkJPX) and [here](http://DATE;TIME;VOLUME;OPEN;CLOSE;MIN;MAX%2007/01/2009;00:00:01;207135;.7198;.71;.7089;.7269%2008/01/2009;00:00:01;225330;.71;.7115;.6953;.7134%2009/01/2009;00:00:01;176534;.7116;.7027;.7008;.712%2012/01/2009;00:00:01;202139;.7022;.6789;.6774;.7023%2013/01/2009;00:00:01;140193;.6787;.6671;.6573;.6793%2014/01/2009;00:00:01;223053;.6672;.6645;.6576;.6812%2015/01/2009;00:00:01;252922;.6642;.6666;.6533;.6702%2016/01/2009;00:00:01;196322;.6666;.6731;.6643;.6797%2019/01/2009;00:00:01;163586;.6731;.6674;.665;.6845%2020/01/2009;00:00:01;231827;.6669;.6485;.6452;.6679%2021/01/2009;00:00:01;230175;.6486;.6579;.6456;.6659%2022/01/2009;00:00:01;214454;.6579;.6541;.6487;.6619%2023/01/2009;00:00:01;221048;.654;.6535;.6414;.6588%2026/01/2009;00:00:01;192533;.6536;.6618;.6489;.6645%2027/01/2009;00:00:01;202281;.6618;.6642;.6569;.6722%2028/01/2009;00:00:01;220706;.6642;.665;.6591;.6733%2029/01/2009;00:00:01;198448;.665;.6497;.6482;.6662%2030/01/2009;00:00:01;205757;.6496;.6352;.6342;.6508%2002/02/2009;00:00:01;184710;.6347;.6303;.6244;.6377%2003/02/2009;00:00:01;208219;.6302;.6487;.6298;.6547%2004/02/2009;00:00:01;224239;.6486;.6426;.635;.6533%2005/02/2009;00:00:01;212688;.6426;.6513;.64;.6583%2006/02/2009;00:00:01;195368;.6513;.6751;.6473;.6803%2009/02/2009;00:00:01;199914;.6751;.6746;.6624;.685%2010/02/2009;00:00:01;241247;.6746;.6569;.6481;.6755%2011/02/2009;00:00:01;200262;.6569;.6533;.6478;.6602%2012/02/2009;00:00:01;223955;.6533;.6568;.6428;.6617%2013/02/2009;00:00:01;168790;.6567;.6563;.6528;.6645%2016/02/2009;00:00:01;127199;.6564;.6529;.6471;.6564%2017/02/2009;00:00:01;202795;.6526;.6366;.6329;.653%2018/02/2009;00:00:01;190700;.6366;.639;.6336;.6433%2019/02/2009;00:00:01;189998;.639;.6446;.638;.6524%2020/02/2009;00:00:01;186257;.6445;.6449;.635;.6499%2023/02/2009;00:00:01;198175;.6448;.6405;.6398;.6549%2024/02/2009;00:00:01;197172;.6406;.6521;.6386;.6542%2025/02/2009;00:00:01;207287;.652;.6466;.6449;.6556%2026/02/2009;00:00:01;179738;.6467;.6466;.6455;.6553%2027/02/2009;00:00:01;216384;.6465;.6383;.6336;.6482%2002/03/2009;00:00:01;204848;.6383;.6291;.6278;.6401%2003/03/2009;00:00:01;204315;.6291;.6372;.6287;.6464%2004/03/2009;00:00:01;197206;.6372;.6465;.6282;.6528%2005/03/2009;00:00:01;190287;.6464;.6386;.6352;.6485%2006/03/2009;00:00:01;178074;.6387;.64;.6365;.6472%2009/03/2009;00:00:01;188777;.6397;.6343;.6302;.6452%2010/03/2009;00:00:01;192153;.6344;.6478;.6338;.649%2011/03/2009;00:00:01;170792;.6478;.6479;.6397;.6526%2012/03/2009;00:00:01;193571;.6479;.6538;.6409;.6578%2013/03/2009;00:00:01;144754;.6538;.6581;.6514;.6607%2016/03/2009;00:00:01;145159;.6576;.6593;.6525;.6639%2017/03/2009;00:00:01;147924;.6594;.6627;.6564;.6632%2018/03/2009;00:00:01;153325;.6627;.6781;.6561;.6818%2019/03/2009;00:00:01;200064;.6781;.6876;.6719;.6944%2020/03/2009;00:00:01;162349;.6876;.6868;.6847;.6932%2023/03/2009;00:00:01;183657;.6873;.7038;.6872;.7064%2024/03/2009;00:00:01;190962;.7038;.6991;.693;.7095%2025/03/2009;00:00:01;172774;.6993;.6987;.6901;.7051%2026/03/2009;00:00:01;148233;.6987;.7019;.6975;.7042%2027/03/2009;00:00:01;131604;.7019;.6937;.686;.7032%2030/03/2009;00:00:01;199669;.6937;.6799;.6767;.6938%2031/03/2009;00:00:01;200324;.68;.6919;.6788;.6971%2001/04/2009;00:00:01;215160;.6921;.6981;.6852;.7002%2002/04/2009;00:00:01;237514;.6981;.7196;.697;.72%2003/04/2009;00:00:01;206219;.7196;.7147;.7054;.723%2006/04/2009;00:00:01;217488;.7152;.7065;.7062;.721%2007/04/2009;00:00:01;231459;.7066;.712;.7039;.7171%2008/04/2009;00:00:01;217515;.7119;.7081;.7029;.7131%2009/04/2009;00:00:01;192404;.708;.7183;.7047;.7206%2010/04/2009;00:00:01;35925;.7184;.7194;.7169;.721%2013/04/2009;00:00:01;111317;.7199;.7316;.7183;.7328%2014/04/2009;00:00:01;222549;.7316;.7228;.7197;.7321%2015/04/2009;00:00:01;236873;.7229;.7276;.7144;.7299%2016/04/2009;00:00:01;244340;.7277;.7198;.7133;.732%2017/04/2009;00:00:01;151602;.7198;.7217;.7164;.7228%2020/04/2009;00:00:01;213079;.7222;.6975;.695;.725%2021/04/2009;00:00:01;166818;.6976;.7069;.6969;.7132%2022/04/2009;00:00:01;230295;.707;.7061;.6997;.7119%2023/04/2009;00:00:01;225838;.706;.7121;.7025;.7158%2024/04/2009;00:00:01;139174;.7121;.7228;.7103;.724%2027/04/2009;00:00:01;312098;.7223;.7064;.7056;.7223%2028/04/2009;00:00:01;316433;.7064;.7069;.6985;.7103%2029/04/2009;00:00:01;218291;.7069;.7252;.7065;.73%2030/04/2009;00:00:01;291588;.7252;.7289;.7232;.7385%2001/05/2009;00:00:01;170823;.729;.7302;.7246;.7349%2004/05/2009;00:00:01;215069;.7307;.7415;.7307;.7421%2005/05/2009;00:00:01;274169;.7415;.7388;.7369;.748%2006/05/2009;00:00:01;328149;.7388;.748;.7333;.7504%2007/05/2009;00:00:01;326602;.7479;.7549;.7456;.7617%2008/05/2009;00:00:01;249332;.7549;.7683;.7504;.7709%2011/05/2009;00:00:01;322413;.7688;.7593;.7565;.7716%2012/05/2009;00:00:01;349797;.7591;.7674;.7558;.7698%2013/05/2009;00:00:01;389011;.7676;.7524;.7504;.7705%2014/05/2009;00:00:01;388758;.7525;.7589;.7461;.762%2015/05/2009;00:00:01;322189;.7589;.749;.7473;.7608%2018/05/2009;00:00:01;325154;.7485;.764;.7443;.7669%2019/05/2009;00:00:01;328829;.7642;.7745;.7623;.7786%2020/05/2009;00:00:01;352149;.7743;.774;.7682;.7811%2021/05/2009;00:00:01;313129;.774;.7804;.7665;.7807%2022/05/2009;00:00:01;294175;.7803;.7824;.7765;.787%2025/05/2009;00:00:01;133134;.7819;.7805;.7768;.7837%2026/05/2009;00:00:01;266208;.7804;.7873;.7699;.7887%2027/05/2009;00:00:01;257801;.7874;.7782;.7741;.7892%2028/05/2009;00:00:01;250271;.7782;.7853;.7754;.7869%2029/05/2009;00:00:01;245473;.7851;.8009;.7842;.8018%2001/06/2009;00:00:01;212151;.8014;.811;.7988;.8154%2002/06/2009;00:00:01;215003;.8109;.8186;.8045;.8232%2003/06/2009;00:00:01;263816;.8186;.8019;.7928;.8265%2004/06/2009;00:00:01;296754;.8019;.8;.7882;.8091%2005/06/2009;00:00:01;212343;.8;.7921;.7913;.8123%2008/06/2009;00:00:01;211255;.7926;.7915;.7823;.799%2009/06/2009;00:00:01;270679;.7915;.8005;.785;.8045%2010/06/2009;00:00:01;198830;.8005;.8029;.7964;.8136%2011/06/2009;00:00:01;206113;.8028;.82;.8025;.8239%2012/06/2009;00:00:01;233604;.82;.8138;.8056;.8209%2014/06/2009;00:00:01;8834;.8138;.8079;.8056;.8138%2015/06/2009;00:00:01;189632;.8078;.7942;.7902;.8093%2016/06/2009;00:00:01;245326;.7942;.7879;.7858;.8069%2017/06/2009;00:00:01;274294;.7879;.7965;.7846;.7998%2018/06/2009;00:00:01;229882;.7965;.7994;.7909;.8055%2019/06/2009;00:00:01;143000;.7994;.8054;.7981;.8139%2022/06/2009;00:00:01;155604;.8054;.7832;.7807;.8055%2023/06/2009;00:00:01;214559;.7831;.7941;.7786;.798%2024/06/2009;00:00:01;227950;.7941;.7968;.7925;.8056%2026/06/2009;00:00:01;107853;.7977;.8073;.797;.8089%2029/06/2009;00:00:01;153894;.8074;.8095;.7979;.8116%2030/06/2009;00:00:01;208890;.8095;.8062;.8034;.8156%2001/07/2009;00:00:01;195160;.8062;.8089;.8018;.8109%2002/07/2009;00:00:01;205875;.809;.7927;.7898;.8095%2003/07/2009;00:00:01;116122;.7927;.7967;.7918;.8008%2006/07/2009;00:00:01;169977;.7962;.7973;.7876;.7983%2007/07/2009;00:00:01;207283;.7974;.7868;.7851;.8039%2008/07/2009;00:00:01;225975;.7866;.7773;.772;.7891%2009/07/2009;00:00:01;211714;.7773;.7843;.7764;.7865%2010/07/2009;00:00:01;203193;.7842;.7789;.7736;.7844%2013/07/2009;00:00:01;224193;.7786;.7837;.7697;.7848%2014/07/2009;00:00:01;195218;.7836;.7946;.781;.7952%2015/07/2009;00:00:01;192817;.7946;.8016;.7921;.8058%2016/07/2009;00:00:01;208974;.8015;.8031;.7956;.8073%2017/07/2009;00:00:01;168251;.8031;.8018;.7964;.8043%2020/07/2009;00:00:01;171155;.8013;.8136;.7999;.8181%2021/07/2009;00:00:01;162896;.8137;.8149;.8085;.8193%2022/07/2009;00:00:01;162907;.8149;.8152;.8096;.8215%2023/07/2009;00:00:01;159347;.8153;.8142;.8104;.8223%2024/07/2009;00:00:01;146476;.8142;.8171;.812;.819) is the data.csv file i'm using.

```
def matrixSeries(matrix):

    nn = 10  #Smoother
    # --Sup/Res Detail
    SupResPeriod = 50
    SupResPercentage  = 100
    PricePeriod = 16
    ob = 200 #Overbought
    os = -200 #Oversold 
    #OBOS = false
    #dynamic = true
    high = np.array(r['max'])
    low = np.array(r['min'])
    close = np.array(r['close'])
    ys1 = (high + low + close * 2 ) / 4
        rk3 = ta.EMA(ys1, nn) 
    rk4 = ta.STDDEV(ys1, nn)
        rk5 = (ys1 - rk3) * 200 /rk4
    rk6 = ta.EMA(rk5, nn)
    up = ta.EMA(rk6, nn)
    down = ta.EMA(up, nn)

    # remove nans in array
    upNans = np.isnan(up)
    up[upNans] = 0 
    downNans = np.isnan(down)
    down[downNans] = 0 

    Oo = np.where(up<down, up, down)    
    Cc= np.where(up<down, down, up )

    #color
    if matrix == 'color':

        color = []
        aa = Oo > Cc
        bb = up > down 
        color = np.where( aa , 'red' , np.where(bb, 'green','red')  )
        return color

    #Body Calculations
    bodyHigh = np.where(up>down, up, down) 
    bodyLow = np.where(Oo<down, up, down)

    bodyCover = np.where( np.any(up>0) and np.any(down>0), bodyLow, np.where( np.any(up<0) and np.any(down<0), bodyHigh,0))
    bodyCover = bodyCover   
    if matrix == 'cover':
        return bodyCover
    if matrix == 'top':
        return Oo
    if matrix == 'bottom':
        return Cc


ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (0,0),sharex=ax1, rowspan=2, colspan=4) 
ax3.bar(r['date'], matrixSeries('top'),  width=1.1,linewidth=0, color=matrixSeries('color'))
ax3.bar(r['date'], matrixSeries('bottom'),  width=1.1,linewidth=0, color=matrixSeries('color'))
ax3.bar(r['date'], matrixSeries('cover'), width=1.1, linewidth=0, color='black' )
ax2.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]. What exactly is the difference between the two plots that you are unhappy with?

Comment: I'm sorry for pasting that much, i'm a noob at Python and it tooks me 3 days to plotting this Indicator. The difference between this two plots are that my plot is not showing the green or red bar on the bottom. [Picture](http://imgur.com/a/HeFvf)

Comment: I'm sure it was a lot of work tinkering this code together. However what we need here to be able to help you is a self-contained example. That is an example code that anyone can run and which contains the least amount of code to still reproduce the issue. This can normally be done by inventing some data arrays and removing all part from the code which is not necessary to still see the problematic part.

Comment: I fix it by my own, anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix it by my own. The bodyCover Calculation was wrong.

```
#Body Calculations
bodyLow = np.where(up>down, up, down).clip(max=0)
bodyHigh = np.where(Oo<down, up, down).clip(min=0)
bodyCover = bodyLow + bodyHigh
```

[image]